# How to download VUEX Store with blobs as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, blob, vuex

I have blobs in my Vuex Store, and I want to download the state of my application as.JSON and restore it.

In general, JSON.stringify(store.state,...) works great without blobs. I just don't know how I can store the Blobs into JSON.

Here is my code. The `if(value instanceof Blob)`-Block contains my attempt to convert the BLOB into JSON.

```
const s = JSON.stringify(store.state
      , (key, value) => {
        // let process = true;
      if (typeof value === 'object') {


        if(value instanceof Blob){

          //I can't get this to work:


          // const reader = new FileReader();

          // // let process = false;
          // reader.onload = function(event){
          //   console.log(JSON.stringify(reader.result));

          //   value = JSON.stringify(reader.result);
          //   return value;
          // };

          // reader.readAsText(value);
          // process = false;

          }

        // Duplicate reference found, discard key
        if (cache.includes(value)) return;

        // Store value in our collection
        cache.push(value);
       }
       if(process){
      return value;
       }
    })

    //download
    const newBlob = new Blob([s], { type: 'application/json;' });
    const filename = `jam-along-${new Date().getTime()}.json`;
    saveAs(newBlob, filename);
    cache = [];


  }
```

Another idea was to use Vuex-Persist to download the store with a customized `saveState: (key, state, storage) =>{...`, but I can't get it to work. I don't want vuex-persist to do anything in the sessionStore or the localStorage, and I want to trigger `saveState` from outside without mutating the store.

Is there any way to download and restore my vuex store?

Thank you!